# Why can I not instantiate std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> with {std::move(first), std::move(second)}?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, initializer-list

I have a simple function which should construct a few objects and return a vector of them while also transferring the ownership. I thought the best way of doing this  is simply returning a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` of the objects (let's say they are `int`).

When I tried the following function:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> create_stuff() {
    auto first = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    auto second = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    return {std::move(first), std::move(second)};
}
```

I was welcomed with a very very long compile error ending with:

```
xmemory0(737): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)':
attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I thought the problem was with the function itself, however the following solution worked fine:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> create_stuff() {
    auto first = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    auto second = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> results;
    results.push_back(std::move(first));
    results.push_back(std::move(second));
    return results;
}
```

Why does the second solution work but not the first one? Is there a workaround that would allow me to use the short and simple syntax with the initializer list?

Comment: Because the initializer list gets passed and then you copy its elements in the vector, you don't move them AFAIK.

Comment: Instead of using `int` in your examples (since pointers to single `int` values seldom makes much sense), I suggest you create a simple class or structure to use. It doesn't have to be fully defined since that's irrelevant to the problem, but at least it would make more sense. For example using a dummy `Foo` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the second solution work but not the first one?

List initialisation syntax that you use invokes the constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`. `std::initializer_list` is not movable though, and `std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is not copiable, so invoking the constructor is not possible.

In the latter example you use the default constructor, so there is no problem.

> Is there a workaround that would allow me to use the short and simple syntax with the initializer list?

You could list initialise an array, and use a pair of move iterators:

```
std::array arr{
    std::make_unique<int>(1),
    std::make_unique<int>(2),
};
return std::vector(
    std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(arr)),
    std::make_move_iterator(std::end(arr))
);
```

---

There was a [proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4166.pdf) to make `std::initializer_list` movable, but it wasn't adopted (hasn't been adopted yet; who knows what future might bring).

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. The question has just been marked as a duplicate and the linked thread offers the same workaround. Thanks for a link to the proposal!

Answer (score 1):

On my platform, the relevant code is:

> ```
>   vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
>    const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
>   : _Base(__a)
>   {   _M_range_initialize(__l.begin(), __l.end(),
>           random_access_iterator_tag());
>   }
> ```

And `_M_range_initialize()` simply *copies* from the iterator, rather than moving-from.